# Do I have to calculate mean in excel or can R make this bar plot?

Tags: r

I need to make a barplot with error bars based on the average of a column in excel. So one column is number of times an elephant swayed titled "Swaying", the other column is called "Species" and the two different variables under the species heading column is African and Asia.

So essentially I need to make one barplot of the average number of swaying behaviours (y-axis) in Asian vs African elephants (x-axis).

my data set is called "elephant"

I'm very new to R, I don't know how to read the coding. I've also tried reading other articles explaining how to do this using "ggplot", whenever I try it doesn't work. My bar graph coding is simple, I use

```
barplot(elephantswaying,
ylab="swaying",
        xlab="species")
```

Could I keep it this simple to make a barplot of the average?

Comment: Please do not delete your questions after you have gotten answers. [stats.SE] isn't just a help line for you. Our purpose is to create a body of information for future searchers. Indeed most of our value goes to people landing here from, say, Google well after questions have been answered. If someone has provided useful information for you, you can accept their answer by clicking the check mark to its left under the vote total. Since you're new here, you may want to take our [tour], which has information for new users.

Comment: Note further that [stats.SE] is not an R tech support site, and that questions only about how to use R are generally off topic here. Such questions can be on topic on [SO], *if* they have a [reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/q/5963269/1217536). If you provide one for this Q, we can migrate it there.

Answer (score 2):

Try for a vertical bar plot (I'll assume that $\textit{count}$ is the variable in your dataset that records the number of swaying behaviours):

```
swayingcounts <- table(elephant$count)
barplot(swayingcounts, main="average number of swaying behaviours in Asian vs African elephants", xlab="species")
```

For a horizontal version:

```
swayingcounts <- table(elephant$count)
barplot(swayingcounts, main="average number of swaying behaviours in Asian vs African elephants", horiz=TRUE, names.arg=c("Asian", "African"))
```

For a boxplot with mean:

```
swayingcounts <- table(elephant$count)
boxplot(swayingcounts~species,data=elephant, main="average number of swaying behaviours in Asian vs African elephants", xlab="species", ylab="swaying")
```

Comment: Thanks for the reply. So this should form a graph showing the two bars (two species) as *mean* number of sways?

Comment: If you are speaking of a boxplot/histogram showing the mean (indicated by a horizontal bar in the rectangular plot), then no. If you want to display the mean, I recommend the boxplot with mean above (updated).